# Cannot access my funds after activation on kukai.app

Tags: tezos-client

I participated in ICO in 2017. I have my Tezos address, mnemonic phrase and etc... I activated my ICO wallet on kukai.app. But the balance is 0. Any ideas how I can access my funds?

Comment: Did you check your contribution at https://check.tezos.com? And did you obtain the activation code at https://verification.tezos.com?

Answer (score 2):

Confirm you entered your password correctly. The mnemonic + password, together, generate a unique key. If you entered password incorrectly, you will still get an address, but it may be the wrong one, showing you a 0 balance.

Look at the PDF you received and verify the public tz1 address is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can join our support chat at this address:
https://riot.im/app/#/room/#kukai:matrix.org